# What does "move up that timetable" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm reading a newspaper and found this paragraph.

> Under the Paris climate deal reached in 2015, China pledged that its emissions would peak around 2030. Mr. Xi promised on Tuesday to move up that timetable, though he did not provide specifics. The bigger surprise, analysts said, was Mr. Xi’s pledge to reach “carbon neutrality” — meaning China’s net carbon emissions will reach zero — by 2060.

What does **move up that timetable** mean here? The original expected emission will peak around at 2030. Does **move up that timetable** means Xi expects the emission will peak around at sometime before 2030 (like 2029) or after 2030 (like 2031)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"move up" generally means to improve or to go to a higher level. here the phrase "move up that time table" means " to reschedule to earlier time".

Comment: Yes, that why I firstly think 2031 is a "higher level" compared to 2030 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think he meant that they will reach peak emissions before 2030.
(If it didn't mean that, he wouldn't be bragging about it.)
To advance a timetable is to move it up, or move it closer to the present.